# Why does raster::extract return several values when using a buffer?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster

I am trying to extract values from a raster based on points. When I run this code

```
library(raster)

raster::extract(my_raster, my_points, method='simple')
```

I get one raster value for each point. However, when I try and do the same with the buffer

```
raster::extract(my_raster, my_points, method='simple', buffer=250)
```

I get several values per each point. I read the documentation of the function in detail, but I can not understand why do I get several raster values when I draw a buffer around my points, or how to avoid this.

Thank you.

Comment: This happens because more pixels are included in the buffer, and if the fun argument is not specified, the function returns the values of all the pixels in the buffer. Try to add `fun="mean"` in the  `extract` call,for example, and you will get one value for every point, i.e. the mean values of each pixel within the buffer. You can pass different functions to the fun argument, also a custom function

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply! I keep getting the error that `Error in fun(x) : could not find function "fun"`, when I put `fun='mean'` in my function. Any idea why this could be? Thanks!

Comment: From the extract documentation: "If y represents points, fun is only used when a buffer is used (and hence multiple values per spatial feature would otherwise be returned)." According to the documentation the function should work. Please add an example that reproduce your error and tomorrow I could try to help you better. Also give more info about your data (raster and point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is condensed from `?extract`

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))
xy <- cbind(-50, seq(-80, 80, by=20))

## no function 
extract(r, xy[1:3,], buffer=1000000)
#[[1]]
# [1] 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 620 621 622 623 624 625 626 627 628 629 630 631
#[[2]]
#[1] 517 518 552 553 554 555
#[[3]]
#[1] 445 446 481 482

## mean works
extract(r, xy[1:3,], buffer=1000000, fun=mean)
#[1] 611.1 541.5 463.5

## but "mean" fails
extract(r, xy[1:3,], buffer=1000000, fun="mean")
#Error in fun(x) : could not find function "fun"
```

Comment: Oh - what a silly mistake on my part. Thanks a lot!